# How do I restrict SSID logon info on a user basis?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, security

Currently, when a user logs on, the network last used is connected. Do not want this to happen when the "guest" user logs on if the previous user was on the primary network. Also, logon credentials to the primary network should not be available to the guest in the WiFi drop-down menu. Seems like this should be a fairly basic security consideration, but numerous web searches have come up empty. I'm not a sophisticated user, so if you have a solution please don't spare the details. Redirecting/selecting wpa_supplicant.conf would seem like a reasonable approach, but don't know how/where to implement.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no "per user" network configuration in linux

Comment: That's why I'm here :).